# How to convert AutoCAD file to Shapefile for map from ArcGIS API 3.2 for JavaScript?

Tags: shapefile, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, convert, autocad

I have an AutoCAD file that I want to convert to Shapefile to appear in a map by API for JavaScript in .net. What do I do?

Comment: do you have ArcGIS desktop?

Comment: yes i have arcgis destop

Comment: load AutoCAD file into are map and right click >export to shapefile.

Comment: ok but i wnat to make convert by code api for javascript that i make project by asp.net and with use this part in it

Comment: You'll need a custom geoprocessing task on the server side to convert the AutoCAD file to a shapefile. From there, you could probably look [here](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/53724-How-to-show-esri-shapefile-on-top-of-a-map-using-arcgis-javascript-api) to make that shapefile appear on your map.

Comment: thanks . but please can you help me the steps what i do to convert autocad to shapefile and show shapfile in map

Answer (score -2):

Open arc catalog , click on connecte folder  ,select where the folder is found, click on ok, right click on the folder ,click on new ,click on shape file then fill sepatial reference  sothat click on  edit ,click on select,click on .....

Comment: The question is asked for conversion by using JavaScript, not just adding a CAD file into ArcMap.

Comment: How does this answer the question?